# How should I try to improve a question that the user doesn't like my edits for?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

Often, when I edit questions, it is because they need editing to be uncrap.
After putting some time into making the following question uncrap, one [person approved the edit, but the user rejected it outright](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/177477), and then made no effort to uncrap their question.

[1366x768 native display resolution on a GT720m - battery life + performance advantage over 1080?](https://superuser.com/questions/681565/1366x768-native-display-resolution-on-a-gt720m-battery-life-performance-adva)

How should I try to repair the question?  Or should I just downvote it because it is crap and move on?

Currently, I'm taking the second tactic because the user seems to not want my help in making their question uncrap, and looking at other questions he's asked, it looks like he's happy asking questions in crap form.

Answer (score 5):

You *did* change the meaning of the post. From:

> Will the video card (GT720M) on the laptop perform better (…) ?

To:

> Can the video card handle the higher resolutions? 
>   (…) why isn't it doing so by default?

That's not what the OP asked, so they were in the right position to reject your edit:

[image]

Honestly, I don't see anything "crap" here. If you can pinpoint what exactly is "crap" about it, maybe that part can be improved (be it spelling, grammar, or perhaps bad wording). I would maybe make the title more readable—but please always try to preserve the original meaning.

You still have a third option: Let the OP know what you think is wrong with their post and have them fix it on their own. That would be much more constructive than downvoting the post without leaving a comment explaining why.

Comment: I guess my point is that he could have at least accepted the edit and then edited it to fix the minor bit that I had gotten confused.

Comment: Remember that it's a relatively new user. They might not know how the system works—often it's easier to reject it, because after all, if they aren't told what's (supposedly) wrong with their question, how would they know what to fix?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see your edit anymore since the OP rolled it back but @slhck has shown you that it was indeed invalid. The question does not seem that bad to me either so I don't understand why you are making a big deal out of it. Granted it is badly written and could use a copy edit but the main question is quite clear:

> So my question is, will the video card (GT720M) on the laptop perform better at a lower resolution than it would on a 1080 resolution?

As a general rule, the OP has the right to keep their question as they want. Most of us are pleased and grateful when our posts are improved but I can understand why someone just rejects what he sees as an invalid edit. Why should I go to the trouble of accepting and editing if I feel that your edit made my question worse?

As far as I can tell, you did not make a "minor" error, you radically changed the question being asked and, of course, it was rejected. That is no reason to downvote, you can either explain why you feel the post can be improved or walk away. In any case, you certainly don't downvote because someone chose not to accept your edit.

---

Now that I have seen your edit I completely agree with the OP. I would have rejected that as well. Your entire edit was a result of your (understandable) misunderstanding of the original question. As far as I can tell, the only change you made worth keeping was changing 1080x1920 to 1920x1080 and adding a space between a full stop and the next sentence. The rest of your edits did not improve the post, only changed its meaning. What would be the point of accepting an edit if improving it would revert the post to its original state?

Comment: I added the link to the edit to the original question.